# How to cache Wordpress DB so it doesn't Query MySql?

Tags: database, wordpress, caching

I have an unlimited host in everything, except the MySql Database, which has limited number of connection at the same time. I want to know if there is any way to cache the posts in the server/host, so it doesn't load them every from the Database every time a visitor loads the page.

This would not be a problem without a lot of traffic, but I have a lot of traffic and this crashed they crashed my Database yesterday.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a caching solution. memcache is one of the most used.

there are also some which does a complete page caching - resin and varnish are quite popular.

in fact there is a varnish plugin fir wordpress at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-varnish/installation/.